# I installed Full Page Cache and now after I click on "Add to Cart" - it says: There are 0 items in your cart

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache

Magento 1.9.1
Full Page Cache program from Amasty

Our website was often extremely slow so I installed a Full Page program from Amasty and now sometimes (like right now) when I go through the order process - after I click on the "Add to cart" button - it says:

```
Product XYZ was added to your shopping cart.
```

And right below that it says:

```
There are 0 items in your cart.
Grand Total $0.00
Subtotal    $0.00
```

I think it's a reason why we are getting only about 10% of the orders we used to get. Any ideas on how to fix this?

*After I deleted all Cache and tried to add 1 item into the cart - it says:

```
There are 4 items in your cart.
```

Meaning those are the 3 I tried to add before plus the one I added now.

---

**ADDED ON JUNE 29TH, 2017:**

As per the suggestion of Raj Purswani and the following link forwarded to me from Amasty:

https://amasty.com/docs/doku.php?id=magento_1:full_page_cache#how_to_hole_punch_cart_welcome_blocks

I did what it says in the manual for "How to hole punch cart/welcome blocks" and added the following list into the amfpc.xml file:

```
<google_analytics cart="1" />
<welcome cart="1" />
<top.links cart="1" />
<wishlist_link cart="1" />
<root cart="1" />
<head cart="1" />
<js_cookies cart="1" />
<optional_zip_countries cart="1" />
<addthis_smartlayers cart="1" />
<shopgate.framework.mobile cart="1" />
<fullajax_js cart="1" />
<sticky_header cart="1" />
<head.child7 cart="1" />
<home_slider cart="1" />
<global_notices cart="1" />
<custom_notice cart="1" />
<header cart="1" />
<store_currency cart="1" />
<store_language cart="1" />
<compare_link cart="1" />
<top.search cart="1" />
<top.search.content cart="1" />
<ANONYMOUS_76 cart="1" />
<minicart cart="1" />
<catalog.topnav cart="1" />
<topnav.sidemenu cart="1" />
<topnav.sidemobilemenu cart="1" />
<sidemenu cart="1" />
<mobile.nav cart="1" />
<bml.center.logo cart="1" />
<home_slider cart="1" />
<ANONYMOUS_77 cart="1" />
<global_messages cart="1" />
<ajaxcart_mask cart="1" />
<page_content_heading cart="1" />
<messages cart="1" />
<ANONYMOUS_78 cart="1" />
<cart_sidebar cart="1" />
<catalog.compare.sidebar cart="1" />
<right.reports.product.viewed cart="1" />
<global_cookie_notice cart="1" />
<sale.reorder.sidebar cart="1" />
```

Does that suppose to exclude those elements? I haven't been able to verify whether that made any difference because right after the change - the problem was the same so I had to delete all Cache from within the Admin panel. And every time I did that in the past - the problem just went away.

**I also started to have another problem and that is when customers tried to add a product to the shopping cart - it would add a completely different product! (I guess this is what simonthesorcerer says below) Any suggestions on how to fix that?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude below things from caching:

1. header
2. top.links
3. cart_sidebar
4. catalog.compare.sidebar
5. right.reports.product.viewed
6. messages and global_messages
7. global_cookie_notice
8. sale.reorder.sidebar

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for helping. Would you see my updated information in the original post please? Is this what you were suggesting I would do? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't configure the full page cache properly and should ask for help at the extension provider. First, you should disable the full page cache.

A full page cache (FPC) basically is so fast because it saves the HTML code of the page and then serves it to all customers. In this process, the FPC tries to avoid asking the shop-software what it should do - if you request the same URL as the person before, you will see what she has seen. There are possibilities to work around it, and most likely the extension you are using has some configuration options. You should, however, first test them in a dev-system because they may strongly depend on the theme you use and on other plugins installed in your shop.

With your current settings, it might happen that:

- customers don't see their cart items
- customers see cart items of other customers
- customers see addresses and order data from other customers
- your tracking, for example Google Analytics, goes wild and tracks nonsense
- a lot more depending on you store